# Mechanism for caching active requests (coroutines)

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, kotlin-coroutines

I needed to implement caching of active requests and I did it as follows:

```kt
private val requestJobCache: MutableMap<RequestBody, Deferred<Response>> = mutableMapOf()

suspend fun fetch(body: RequestBody): Response {
    // ... some code
}

suspend fun get(body: RequestBody): Response {
    if (requestJobCache.containsKey(body)) {
        return requestJobCache[body]!!.await()
    }

    return coroutineScope {
        try {
            val request = async { fetch(body) }

            requestJobCache[body] = request
            return@coroutineScope request.await()
        }
        finally {
            val finishedRequestJob = requestJobCache.remove(body)

            // ...
            // what does finishedRequestJob?.isCompleted equal?
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but there is one strange thing: in theory, `finishedRequestJob?.IsCompleted` should always return `true`, because this code is executed in the `finally` block after the asynchronous function has received the result. However, in practice, this method *sometimes* returns `false`.

Why can this happen, where did I make a mistake in my reasoning, and how to implement this correctly?

Comment: You should really synchronize access to `requestJobCache`. I'm not sure if this is what happens here, but note that for example between `requestJobCache.containsKey(body)` and `requestJobCache[body]!!.await()` another thread/coroutine may `remove()` the item, causing NPE. Similarly, multiple coroutines may check `containsKey()` for the same item, then both of them will start a request and then `finishedRequestJob?.isCompleted` for one of them will return `false`.

Comment: @broot, good point! The original implementation uses `ConcurrentHashMap`, but I don't know how idiomatic this method is for kotlin, I'm going to find/ask a separate question about it.

Comment: Using `ConcurrentHashMap` does not solve this situation, because the problem occurs between `containsKey()` and `requestJobCache[body]` (both getting and setting). You would need to use mutex or similar technique, but `coroutineScope()` makes it a little harder.

Comment: What pitfalls are there with `coroutineScope`? Couldn't I just use `withLock {}` everywhere I work with a collection?

Comment: Look, mutex isn't a magic thing that automatically makes the code thread safe. If you put `containsKey()` inside `withLock()` and `requestJobCache[body]` inside another `withLock()` then you will still have exactly the same problem. The point is that you have to make sure that no-one will touch `requestJobCache` between checking `containsKey()` and retrieving/adding from/to it. You need to put both `containsKey()` and `requestJobCache[body]` in a single `withLock()` block. The problem is: we can't suspend inside `withLock()`, because we would block everyone trying to use `get()` function.

Comment: See my answer. I redesigned the code, so all 3 operations: checking for the key existence, retrieving deferred and adding deferred are in the same `withLock()` block, but it is still relatively quick to execute, so we don't block other users of `get()` function.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of this is that access to `requestJobCache` is not synchronized. For example, between `requestJobCache.containsKey(body)` and `requestJobCache[body]!!.await()` another thread/coroutine may `remove()` the item, causing `NullPointerException`. Similarly, multiple coroutines may check `containsKey()` for the same item, then all of them will start a request and then `finishedRequestJob?.isCompleted` for some of them will return `false`.

To fix this, we need to synchronize access to `requestJobCache`. This is a little complicated in this case, because of suspends and `coroutineScope()`, but we should be able to workaround these problems with the code like this:

```kotlin
private val requestJobCache: MutableMap<RequestBody, CompletableDeferred<Response>> = mutableMapOf()
private val requestJobCacheLock = Mutex()

@Suppress("DeferredResultUnused")
suspend fun get(body: RequestBody): Response {
    val (existed, deferred) = requestJobCacheLock.withLock {
        requestJobCache[body]
            ?.let { true to it }
            ?: (false to CompletableDeferred<Response>().also {
                requestJobCache[body] = it
            })
    }

    return if (existed) {
        deferred.await()
    } else {
        val result = runCatching { fetch(body) }
        deferred.completeWith(result)

        requestJobCacheLock.withLock {
            requestJobCache.remove(body)
        }

        result.getOrThrow()
    }
}
```

Note I didn't have a chance to test this code, so it may contain errors. I hope you get the idea.